# Log into Launchpad from python script

Tags: python, authentication, urllib

How can I log into my Launchpad account in a python script? Any sample code would be appreciated.

The login url is https://launchpad.net/+login and then redirect to something like https://login.launchpad.net/fJLVSRbxPfKTpVDr/+decide

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest looking into the official [launchpadlib](https://launchpad.net/launchpadlib), instead of rolling your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could check bzrlib it has [some integration with launchpad](http://people.canonical.com/~mwh/bzrlibapi/bzrlib.plugins.launchpad.html).